# C Global variable with same name as system function causes segfault?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, global-variables

Consider this extremely simple setup:

Contents of foo.c:

```
#include "bar.h"

int socket[128];

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        bar();

        return 0;
}
```

Contents of bar.h

```
void bar(void);
```

Contents of bar.c:

```
#include <sys/socket.h>

void bar(void)
{
        socket(AF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM,0);
}
```

Compile:

```
gcc -Wall -pedantic foo.c bar.c -o foobar
```

Run

```
./foobar
```

When this program compiles and links with no error, and when it runs it causes a segmentation fault at the call to socket() in bar.c. Changing the name of global variable in foo.c to something other than 'socket' fixes this. But I don't understand *why*? Shouldn't this be a linker error at least?

Comment: `socket` is an array of `int` and then it also is a function, I'm amazed that this even links.

Comment: If you declare a global variable and a function with the same name in another file, then the linker does throw an error. I guess my question is: why does't it throw an error when the function in question is from a system library instead of a project file?

Comment: Could be defined as a weak symbol. Impossible to know for sure what goes on your system. You may need to dig a little.

Comment: You can use the [nm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nm_(Unix)) command to find which symbols are weak.

Comment: Try adding some compiler flags, such as `-Wall` so that the compiler could point you in the right direction

Comment: Try adding a `static` to the global var declaration and see if error persists. If the error goes away you have your answer.
It's quite possible for the `socket` variable symbol to have precedence over external libraries when linking.

Comment: The global variable is overriding the default definition of `socket`.  When linking, you would normally pick up the library version of `socket`, but since you defined your own version, it's overriding the library version.  The compiler doesn't see the problem because you're compiling the two files separately, and you're not including `sys/socket.h` in the file that defines `socket`.

Comment: @StoryTeller: This is a routine behavior of linkers: A module is taken from a library only if needed (it defines a symbol used but not defined by the executable under construction). Weak symbols are not involved. And it is not impossible to know what happens in OP’s system. They are using Unix features, and this is typical behavior of Unix tools.

Comment: @immortal: What do you envision `-Wall` will report? `int socket[128];` is legal C code.

Comment: @P.W: `nm` is not useful here; weak symbols are not involved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The common behavior of linkers is to take an object module from a library if and only if that module defines a symbol that is used but not resolved in the executable being constructed.

This is an important and necessary behavior to avoid conflicts between symbols in programs and symbols in library modules that the author did not use. Later languages, like C++, addressed this issue by separating name spaces (such as `std::`). But, generally, we have to deal with the fact that many authors naturally use names for their own routines or objects like `read` or `write` that conflict with library routines. Linkers must allow this.

So, when your program defines `socket`, the linker allows that definition and does not take it from the library. The linker does not know that the code in one of your modules uses `socket` as a function while the definition in another module is for an object.

Answer (score 1):

`socket` is a pointer to an array.

From the other file you consider `socket` to be a pointer to a function cf. declaration of `socket.h`.

The linker can link these because *the linker does not know the types*.

You have to have a common header in which you declare the exported symbols in order to catch such things.

If the linker finds a symbol `socket` in the library you use in linking, it will insert the address of this. Otherwise, it will link with `socket` from the posix library of the system.